How to connect xlsx file to R from Onedrive
I'm seeking a way to connect a ".xlsx" file from a shared OneDrive link. The OneDrive where the file is stocked is not mine but I've full access to the .xlsx file. My code:
library(curl)
library(readxl)

url <- "https://onedrive.live.com/:x:/g/personal/D7F26BE16D487B10/EYJxLYphlkRFogUmL7LhO4QBEym63JCSoZVQXXgeXG6ptA?resid=D7F26BE16D487B10!s8a2d718296614544a205262fb2e13b84&ithint=file%2Cxlsx&e=Oj2gQq&migratedtospo=true&redeem=aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3gvYy9kN2YyNmJlMTZkNDg3YjEwL0VZSnhMWXBobGtSRm9nVW1MN0xoTzRRQkV5bTYzSkNTb1pWUVhYZ2VYRzZwdEE_ZT1PajJnUXE"

temp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
browseURL(url)
curl_download(url, temp_file)

data <- read_excel(temp_file)
head(data)

and my error message:
Error in utils::unzip(zip_path, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file 'C:\Users\La Machine\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYBemJU\file44dc762e4fef.xlsx' cannot be opened

I tried the methods reported in this post: Reading OneDrive files to R
I tried:

Download the file
and get the URL in download page (Ctrl+J in Chrome) but don't have the same URL format as seen in the related post.
The curl package which seems OK. But I've this error concerning zip file. In my environment the file is ".xlsx" but when I tried to open it in Excel the file wasn't recognized. I also try zip package to unzip it. But because of the ".xlsx", it didn't work. The file should be ".zip" I think?

In fine I want to download the file into R, work on it, and export it again to OneDrive
Any ideas please?

Check the sensitivity label of the .xlsx file.  If it's confidential then you may need to change it to general or public.

Thank you. Do you know a way to do that without giving general access since the data are effectively confidential.
